# Why ' in ' is so much faster than ' = ' in SQL Select?

Tags: sql, oracle

This select's execution time is approximately 25 ~ 30 sec.

```
SELECT *
  FROM custinfo cs
 WHERE cs.idcust = (SELECT cust_id
                        FROM customers
                       WHERE id = 1230)
```

Execution plan for ' = ':

[image: Execution plan for ' = ']

But if I change ' = ' for ' in ', then it becomes so much faster about 0.040 ~ 0.060-sec average.

```
SELECT *
      FROM custinfo cs
     WHERE cs.idcust in (SELECT cust_id
                            FROM customers
                           WHERE id = 1230)
```

Execution plan for ' in ':

[image: Execution plan for ' in ']

And there have been opposite cases like this, where ' = ' was faster than ' in '.

Does anybody know the reason why simple syntax change makes this much difference in performance and execution time?

When is ' = ' is faster than ' in ' or vice versa?
Are there some conditions for which to use in what cases?

- I'm using dblink for my table. Maybe that's what's affecting my query?
- Welp, guys, Here's the thing... Now both of my queries run for about ~0.10 sec. So now I can't find an Execution plan for my queries when they were running slow. And I have absolutely no idea why my queries performance changed in a day... Like, I can only guess the problem was with our servers, but, why did it only affect my 1 query, while the other runs normally?
  Still, here's my execution plans:

' = '

[image: ' = ' Execution Plan]

' in '
[image: ' in ' Execution Plan]

Comment: Only execution plans can tell you the difference. How can we guess? You may also check: [Monitoring Database Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/monitoring-database-operations.html#GUID-CEED2A89-51DE-42AC-B2BD-CAD3D6E25807)

Comment: Of course, that's the case. But I still can't understand anything when looking at the plan. So I wanted to know if it's a common occurrence, which happens because of syntax, or not ...

Comment: Please post the execution plan of both queries. We can help you to read them.

Comment: I would guess that the table statistics are stale, so the Oracle optimizer is confused.

Comment: You should post entire execution plans as plain text. And the most interesting part is hidden: E-rows, A-rows and times. If Oracle used anyone of them, it consider it as good enough and there's no reason not to trust it. Just looking at the operators the first one should be much faster, but you tell is not. So the easiest way to analyse the execution is realtime monitoring to find out actual "slow" places

Comment: The optimiser is free to rearrange the query internally. Perhaps one or the other transforms into something very different. Also, `= (subquery)` tells the optimiser to expect one row, so it may choose to drive the query from the subquery, where `in (subquery)` could give many rows, in which case it may calculate (incorrectly as it happens) that it should start with custinfo. A working example and the full execution plan would help a lot.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  Please check the updated question

Comment: @TheImpaler Please check the updated question

Comment: @astentx Please check the updated question

Comment: Both the execution plans are the same. Looks like it was the case Gordon mentioned: statistics was stale and optimizer didn't know correct estimates. Anyway, filtering should be much faster than any type of join. It really worth to spend some time to get familiar with realtime monitoring via EM or [`dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.html#GUID-04851EB0-32AB-424C-91A1-65AD9220A690) not to guess in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "IN" means "there might be more that one row returned in this subquery, please check them all" whereas "=" means "there will be only one line returned from subquery" otherwise it would be an error.

Having that info the optimizer build different query plans. For "="-query it executes subquery first and then filters the custInfo table out.

For the "IN" query optimizer performs a join operation as if you've written following query

```
SELECT *
  FROM custinfo cs
  JOIN customers c
    ON cs.idcust = c.cust_id
 WHERE c.id = 1230;
```

This is why execution time differs. It can take longer or not depending on you data selectivity, indexes, partitioning and so on

UPD. From the execution plans you've uploaded I see the following

1. For the "=" query:

```
1.1. It competely scans the MT_OPERATION_OUT table (FULL TABLE SCAN), captures the result
1.2. Then it accesess another table on remote DB, presumably scans it too (REMOTE)
1.3. Filters data it got from remote.
```

2. For the "IN" query:

```
2.1. It competely scans the MT_OPERATION_OUT table (FULL TABLE SCAN), captures the result
2.2. Sorts what it got on the previous step (SORT UNIQUE)
2.3. Then it accesess another table on remote DB, presumably scans it too (REMOTE)
2.4. Performs a join (NESTED LOOPS)
```

So to me it seems that for some reason the db needs more time to filter data from remote db that to join it using "nested loops" method.

Comment: If the optimizer executes subquery first for ' = ', then shouldn't it run even faster? If I understood correctly, then my subquery returns  '318140', and if I just execute my query with that number, it gives about the same time as ' in '.  Or did I misunderstood something? Pleas, clarify it for me

Comment: @SUMguy my comment was " means "there will be only one line returned from subquery" otherwise it would be an error."

Comment: @ekochergin Thanks for the answer, mate. Now I get to understand the plan a little bit more. And I just checked queries in the remote DB itself, without dblink (or db_link to my original DB), and it was as you said, it worked just normally there, and ' = ' worked even a little bit faster. So it seems like, my DB link makes everything slower. But I still don't get the reason why the DB needs more time to filter data from remote DB than to join it using the "nested loops" method. Welp, still, thanks for the answer )

Comment: @SUMguy what I'm getting is "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more that one row"

Comment: @SUMguy if you are using ' = ', then your subquery can't return either more than 1 row or 1 column, so only 1 cell and its data_type should be the same too. What you are saying, will only apply to ' in ', where it will return as many as cell values subquery returns

Comment: @Isi you're always welcome. Post whole execution plan please with cardinalities, predicates and so on. Let's see if I can find out

Comment: Mate, now both of my queries run as if nothing has happened, so I wasn't able to find an execution plan for when they were running slowly. But pls check updated question for their present Plans

Comment: @Isi there is an index appeared on the table since yesterday. So the database doesn't need it to full scan table. This is why both plans have been changed and became identical